# Deploy Django Server on Apache+Ubuntu on a special port

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

I have done a simple Django Project for university.

Now I want to show it on my own hosted virtual server, like `www.myserver.com:8001`

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with apache2.

In `/etc/apache/site-available` I have a con file named: `uniproject.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:8001>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/uniproject/"
        Servername www.myserver.com:8001
        Alias /static /var/www/uniproject/static/
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/uniproject/uniproject.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/uniproject/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` I wrote `Listen 8001`

In `/var/www/uniproject/uniproject.wsgi`

```
import os
import sys
sys.path = ['/var/www/uniproject'] + sys.path
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'uniproject.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

After `a2ensite uniproject.conf`  and `service apache2 restart` I'm calling `www.myserver.com:8001`
there comes

```
Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

My goal is to have, later on, about running three to five django apps/servers on my site reachable like 
`www.myserver.com:8001`, `www.myserver.com:8002`, `www.myserver.com:8003`, etc ...
but what I do wrong?

I'm using Django 1.7.1 without virtualenv

The Apache Log says:

> Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/uniproject, referer: http://www.myserver.com:8001/

The file structure in `/var/www/uniproject` is:

- db3.sqlite
- uniproject
- uniprojectBackend
- uniprojectwsgi
- manage.py
- static
- templates

In `/var/www/uniproject/uniproject` are the default django files when creating a new project (`setting.py`, `urls.py`, `wsgi.py`, `__init__.py`)

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root  4096 Dec 21 21:50 uniproject
```

Comment: Apache should log something about that in it log. That would be really helpful if you copied the relevant lines here as there may be several causes.

Comment: The log entry indicates it's nothing to do with the port, but that it can't find the uniproject directory. Does that directory exist, with permissions so it is visible by the apache user? Have you tried the same setup without the port stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is how I solved my issue. 
I'm now disabling the port stuff and use subdomain instead.

HOWTO: "**Deploy various numbers of Django Apps on Apache2 running on Ubuntu 14.04**"
*First:*

```
cd /etc/apache2/site-available
sudo nano someproject.conf
```

in someproject.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName someproject.mysite.com
ServerAlias www.someproject.myssite.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/someproject/"
Alias /static /var/www/someproject/static/
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/someproject/wsgi.py
<Directory /var/www/someproject/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

after that run:

```
sudo a2ensite someproject.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

*Second:*

```
cd /var/www/
django-admin.py startproject someproject
cd someproject
sudo nano wsgi.py
```

in wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys

path = '/var/www/someproject'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'someproject.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

now visit: `someproject.mysite.com`

This is done with django 1.7.1
Make Sure all python modules are also installed (e.g. lxml, feed parser etc.)

Sometimes there will be a bug (happen to me) in settings.py

remove or comment in settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

After every edit in the django project run

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Hope this helps anyone.

With this method I'm running three django server/apps on my VM.